# How to filter by language in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

In my firebase console showing only 6 user properties(Age, App Version, Device Model, Gender, New/Established, OS Version ) but as per documentation there are 25 automatically collected user properties. I like to filter on Language properties. Is it require to Big Query ?

Comment: Did you find a way to filter by language?

Comment: I have used user property to get the desire statics.

Answer (score 2):

Though firebase collect language data from user but It not provides any stander  filter by language. I have solved this issue using **User properties**.

about [User Properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties)

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("App_Lanaguage", Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
```

I wrote the above code in my Application class.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is already published in play store you don't need to add user property into firebase.

You can filter by device language in Play developer console.
Go to your application dashboard > Statistics > CONFIGURE REPORT > Choose Language

Comment: There is no Statistics menu in dashboard

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create an audience and use the user properties you've mentioned as the filters in the audience builder. Please note that the audience will start to accumulate data after you created it. Once the audience has data, you can use it as a filter in your analytics reports on the Firebase console.